# 500 Internal Server Error caused by mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds

Tags: php

I have a `php` page that runs a number of loops and queries and `database` updates etc. It can take some time to run and after a minute, I get the `500 Internal Server Error`. I don't have access to the `logs` but my hosting service has forwarded a copy and it seems that it is a `timeout` related error:

> mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds

I have included:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 9000);
set_time_limit(0);
```

In the `php` page but it still causes the `500` error. I can't access any of the `config` files. Is there any other way I can increase the `timeout` for this page?

I have also tried putting

```
set_time_limit(59);
```

at the start of each loop through. If this is meant to reset the clock then I can't see that I should have a problem but the error persists.

NOTE: I am 99% sure that it is not an error in the script itself as sometimes it goes through and other times times it doesn't with exactly the same data.

Comment: You can use the set_time_limit() to reset the time limit

Comment: @Harikrishnan max_execution_time = 60 seconds (i.e. my error) and I am not sure what time_limit you are referring to.

Comment: @Answers_Seeker I have included that in my question. Setting it at 0 should mean that there is no limit (as I understand it).

Comment: Right, i was thinking about the [reseting behavior](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) which could do the trick

Comment: @Answers_Seeker Oh I see. I have added an edit to include this. It is still struggling.

Comment: Just check values are set correctly by `ini_get('max_execution_time')`

Comment: @Harikrishnan Very helpful. Been playing with that and although ini_set('max_execution_time', 9000); was written at the beginning it didn't seem to be being applied. Moved it lower down into the page and it worked. Thanks!!